# how to pass logic app run id to external services in order to enable tracking?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

**Do logic apps provide us access to the identifier (id per run)?**

Logic apps generate an ID for every run, such as:

[image]

How do we capture this `identifier` within the logic app run, in order to be able to pass it as a tracking id to downstream services?

For example, the flow might be:

1. run logic app
2. call HTTP function, passing identifier, such as *08586417615830234507761283917CU08* to it

**How do we get the identifier inside of the run?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `workflow().run.name` to get it, this is the description about [workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#workflow).

[image]

[image]

Hope this could help you.